# retrieving value from a jsArray in scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have this variable in scala with

`val id: Option[(String, JsValue)]= Some((studentId,{"courseId":"765"}))`

I want to retrieve that **id 765** but I am not able to make it happen. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you already try? BTW, there is no JsArray in your code...

Comment: @sumit gawande which json library you are using?

Comment: json library of play framework I.e. play.json

Answer (score 3):

Please refer [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson) to know more about play json basics.
Here is a quick but dirty way 
`val cid = id.map{ jscid => (jscid._2 \ "courseId").as[String]}.get` 
It will give you 
`cid: String = 765`. 
**Beware** of .as and .get . Put your validation and error handling.

Comment: `.get` should never be used

Comment: @cchantep: I agree. Pattern matching (or some other way) should be used and error should be handled as per requirement. I have put a warning.